# Regular expression match all numbers after the last dash?

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to find the last instance of numbers after last dash in a string so

`test-123-2-456` would return `456`

`123-test` would return `""`

`123-test-456` would return `456`

`123-test-456sdfsdf` would return `456`

`123-test-asd456` would return `456`

The expression, `@"[^-]*$"`, does not match the numbers though, and I have tried using [\d] but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, the simplest solution would be something like this:

```
(\d+)[^-]*$
```

This will match one or more digits, captured in group 1, followed by zero or more of any character *other than* a hyphen, followed by the end of the string. In other words, it will match any sequence of digits as long as there are no hyphens between that sequence and the end of the string. You then just have to extract group 1 from the match. For example:

```
var inputs = new[] {
    "test-123-2-456",
    "123-test",
    "123-test-456",
    "123-test-456sdfsdf",
    "123-test-asd456"
};
foreach(var str in inputs)
{
    var m = Regex.Match(str, @"(\d+)[^-]*$");
    Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", str, m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Produces:

```
test-123-2-456 --> 456
123-test --> 
123-test-456 --> 456
123-test-456sdfsdf --> 456
123-test-asd456 --> 456
```

Alternatively, if you could use a [negative lookahead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookahead_assertion) like this:

```
\d+(?!.*-)
```

This will match one or more digit characters so long as they are not followed by a hyphen. Only the digits will be included in the match.

Note that these two options behave differently if there are two or more sets of numbers after the last `-`, e.g. `foo-123bar456`. In this case it's not entirely clear what you want to happen, but the first pattern will simply match everything starting from the first sequence of digits to the end (`123bar456`) with group 1 only containing the first sequence of digits (`123`). If you'd like to change this so that it only captures the last sequence of digits, place a `\d` inside the character class (i.e. `(\d+)[^\d-]*$`). The second second pattern would produce a separate match for each sequence digits (in this example, `123` and `456`) but the `Regex.Match` method will only give you the first match.

Comment: "test-123-dfg456" with the above matches dfg456

Comment: @user1853454 You have to extract the first group, I've included an example. However, I did notice a problem with my original pattern; I've corrected it in my updated answer.

Comment: thats great sorry to be a pain could you perhaps explain it slightly ill mark you as the correct answer

Comment: @user1853454 I'd be glad to explain. Exactly what part are you confused about?

Comment: i dont understand (\d+) being before [^-] thought digit match would be after [^-]

Comment: @user1853454 Whoops. I corrected my pattern in my last edit, but not my description of the pattern. Hopefully my updated answer helps to explain the logic here.

Answer (score 0):

The latest group from this RegEx can get the last number for you:

```
[^-A-z][0-9]+[^A-z]
```

If you are looking at groups, you can write this code by matching groups to get the latest number:

```
var inputs = new[] {
    "test-123-2-456",
    "123-test",
    "123-test-456",
    "123-test-456sdfsdf",
    "123-test-asd456"
};


 var m = Regex.Match(str, @"([0-9]*)");
 if(m.Groups.Length>1) //This will avoid the values starting with numbers only.
   Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", str, m.Groups[m.Groups.Length-1].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to apply two regex-functions. Take the result of the first one as the input for the second one.

The first regex is:

```
-[0-9]+[^-]+$    // Take the last peace of your string lead by a minus (-)
                 // followed by digits ([0-9]+)
                 // and some ugly rest that doesn't contain another minus ([^-]+$)
```

The second regex is:

```
-[0-9]+          // Seperate the relevant digits from the ugly rest
                 // You know that there can only be one minus + digits part in it
```

Tested here: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx